# Asynchronously display a message to the user when an event occurs on the server (app.js / client.js)

Tags: node.js

I am totally a novice in NodeJS and I am trying to implement an application in NodeJS that responding to a GET type call either storing values ​​in a database or, in some other way, allowing a client web to show a message automatically to the user.

I was thinking that the server (Example.- app.js) responding to a GET would save values ​​in BD and that the client (Example.- client.js) would read this database from time to time to show a message to the user .

Any ideas how it could be done more efficiently without having to go through this regular consultation process?

Thank you

Comment: You definitely should start with `Express.js` for this case. (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)
It's exactly what you want. Your `web-server` will receive `GET` from the user, then do any logic that you program in to it, and then shows the client data from database by request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know if I explained myself.

I have the following structure:
+ server.js
+ /static/index.html
/static/js/index.js

Index.html imports the file index.js

Comment: From server.js I can use libraries such as sqlite3 to write to database but from index.js it always gives me the error that it cannot find the sqlite3 module or any other.
Any idea what the error might be?

I already use express.js to mount an application with the / static / entry point and receive requests with app.get.

Comment: The initial question was that if a user is connected to index.html + index.js and the server.js application receives a request, how can I make the user aware of the event without having to refresh the screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am a novice, but I am hazarding an answer because I think I am in-touch with your confusion.

## About Protocols

It sounds to me like you are realizing that the [message exchange pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_pattern) embodied by HTTP, the [request-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) pattern, may not be the optimal solution for client-server interactions where the client wants to stay apprised of updates to certain data within the database.  Ultimately, the client can't know when a pertinent database update occurs, but because the server can not initiate a data exchange in the request-response pattern, the client must periodically send requests blindly to check for changes.

You would be correct to see this as inefficient.  Alternative message response patterns exist and are widely used for this and related reasons.  The [publish/subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) embodied by [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) is one such alternative pattern. This is used in the Facebook messenger app.

However, for most web-apps you will be using HTTP, and that's fine because for most web apps, either the client only wants data when your app has the user's attention, or the inefficiency of blind update requests isn't costly enough to justify using something else.

The upshot will be that you do end up with a bit of a "regular consultation process" between client and server, but it doesn't have to disrupt your user's experience.

## So how is it done with HTTP?

Three tools come to your aid:

1. Manipulation of the response in node/express
2. Asynchronous requests
3. API conventions (like REST)

### Status messages in a response

In the following example using Node, express, and mongoose, my app has received a POST request containing data.  I check if the data is valid, and if it is, I enter the data into the database.  I also send a simple text message in the response indicating to the client if the data was saved.  The point is there is both a database-update and a response that depends on what happened on the server.

```
app.post('/meetups/:meetId/names', (req, res) => {

    // validate the input.
    if (!validName(req.body.name)) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid name: user not created");
        return null;
    }

    Meetup.findById(req.params.meetId, function (err, foundMeetup) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("<h3>It's not you, it's us.</h3><p>We encountered an error while searching for that event.</p>");
            return null;
        } else if (foundMeetup == null) {
            res.status(404).send("sorry, we can't find that event.");
            return null;
        } else {
            foundMeetup.names.push(req.body.name);
            foundMeetup.save();
            res.send("Success!  Your name is saved.");  // implied 200 status. 
        }
    });
});
```

Express gives you quite a few tools for creating responses.  `res.sendFile()` `res.redirect('')` and `res.render()` are worth a look. http://expressjs.com/

### Asynchronous requests

You may want to read data from your server without reloading the whole page, or send data to your server without reloading or loading a different page.  In order to pull this off, the request the client sends must be asynchronous.  There are several ways to do this. [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp) and fetch() are prevalent. These go in your front-end javascript.

### API conventions

In my code example, I used a POST request.  This is to adhere with the guidelines of REST.  Because I am creating a new record in the database which will store the data that the client sends, POST is the appropriate request method. If I were to be updating an existing record, PUT would be appropriate.  To simply read, I would use GET.

Thus, we do see this "regular consultation process" in that, by convention, we don't try to do everything with a single GET request.  We send an initial GET request to load up whatever is at the desired URL, then as we transition into manipulating data, we use POST, PUT, DELETE, and GET as the situation dictates. This helps you manage complexity and makes your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using AJAX (XMLHttpRequest).
I send the POST request asynchronously containing the form data formatted as JSON and display the server's response in the browser without reloading the page.  This solution uses vanilla javascript on the client, node and express on the server.  I have omitted boilerplate.

### Server code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3003;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({type: 'application/json'}));

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port %s", port);
});

app.post('/route', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    if (req.body.name1.length < 4) {
        res.status(400).send("Name too short. No data entered");
        return;
    }
    // TODO: Save the data to database here. 
    res.send("Name has been entered.")
});
```

### Client code

/public/index.html

```html
<html>
<form onsubmit="sendPostRequest(event)">
  <label for="name-1"><p>Enter a name at least 4 characters long.</p></label>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name-1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>

<em id="message" hidden></em>

</html>

<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

/public/index.js

```js
let messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');

let xhrPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrPost.onload = processXhrResponse;

function sendPostRequest(event) {
  let form = event.target;
  let objToSend = {
    name1: form.name1.value
  };

  // this is what sends the asynchronous request
  xhrPost.open('POST', '/route');
  xhrPost.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  xhrPost.send(JSON.stringify(objToSend));

  // this stops the normal form-submit actions, which would refresh the page. 
  event.preventDefault();
}

// This function gets executed when the xhrPost 
// has received the server's response. 
function processXhrResponse() {

  // put the message from the server into the DOM and reveal it. 
  messageDiv.innerText = this.responseText;
  messageDiv.removeAttribute('hidden');

  // use the response status to style the message. 
  if (this.status >= 400) {
    messageDiv.style = 'color: red;';
  } else {
    messageDiv.style = '';
  }
}
```